# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 - Compass <> MongoDB Replication Set connection challenges

Tags: mongodb

I'm testing using docker compose for a replicated set on my local machine and am having trouble with getting Compass connected and functioning with the local set.  Everything has deployed fine and I can see the exposed ports listening on the host machine.  I just keep getting ECONNREFUSED.

Here is the Docker Compose file.

```yaml
services:
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo:latest
    networks: 
      - mongo-network
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30001:27017
    volumes:
      - md1:/data/db 
    restart: always
    command: mongod --replSet mongo-net
  
  mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: mongo2
    image: mongo:latest
    networks: 
      - mongo-network
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30002:27017
    volumes:
      - md2:/data/db       
    restart: always
    command: mongod --replSet mongo-net
  
  mongo3:
    hostname: mongo3
    container_name: mongo3
    image: mongo:latest
    networks: 
      - mongo-network
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30003:27017
    volumes:
      - md3:/data/db 
    restart: always
    command: mongod --replSet mongo-net

  mongoinit:
    image: mongo
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2
      - mongo3
    command: >
      sh -c "mongosh --host mongo1:27017 --eval 
      '
      db = (new Mongo("localhost:27017")).getDB("test");
      config = {
      "_id" : "mongo-net",
      "members" : [
        {
          "_id" : 0,
          "host" : "localhost:27017",
          "priority": 1
        },
        {
          "_id" : 1,
          "host" : "localhost:27017",
          "priority": 2
        },
        {
          "_id" : 2,
          "host" : "localhost:27017",
          "priority": 3
        }
      ]
      };
      rs.initiate(config);
      '"      

networks:
  mongo-network:

volumes:
  md1:
  md2:
  md3:
```

The containers and replication set deploy fine and are communicating.  I can see the defined ports exposed and listening.

[image]

My issue is trying to use Compass to connect to the replicated set. I get ECONNREFUSED.

[image]

What's odd is I can actually see the client connecting on the primary logs, but get no other information about what the connection was refused/DCed.

```json
{
    "attr": {
        "connectionCount": 7,
        "connectionId": 129,
        "remote": "192.168.32.1:61508",
        "uuid": "f78c3803-fc7c-4655-9b77-94329bd41a7d"
    },
    "c": "NETWORK",
    "ctx": "listener",
    "id": 22943,
    "msg": "Connection accepted",
    "s": "I",
    "t": {
        "$date": "2022-11-02T18:57:20.032+00:00"
    }
}
{
    "attr": {
        "client": "conn129",
        "doc": {
            "application": {
                "name": "MongoDB Compass"
            },
            "driver": {
                "name": "nodejs",
                "version": "4.8.1"
            },
            "os": {
                "architecture": "arm64",
                "name": "darwin",
                "type": "Darwin",
                "version": "22.1.0"
            },
            "platform": "Node.js v16.5.0, LE (unified)|Node.js v16.5.0, LE (unified)"
        },
        "remote": "192.168.32.1:61508"
    },
    "c": "NETWORK",
    "ctx": "conn129",
    "id": 51800,
    "msg": "client metadata",
    "s": "I",
    "t": {
        "$date": "2022-11-02T18:57:20.034+00:00"
    }
}
{
    "attr": {
        "connectionCount": 6,
        "connectionId": 129,
        "remote": "192.168.32.1:61508",
        "uuid": "f78c3803-fc7c-4655-9b77-94329bd41a7d"
    },
    "c": "NETWORK",
    "ctx": "conn129",
    "id": 22944,
    "msg": "Connection ended",
    "s": "I",
    "t": {
        "$date": "2022-11-02T18:57:20.044+00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: After `rs.initiate(config)` you need to wait some time. Append `while ( !db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000);`

Comment: You added three times the same member `localhost:27017`. Use different ports and/or hostnames